# Python3 cannot find module installed by pip3 even though it is deffintley installed

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I have a folder structure

```
root
|-setup.py
|-src
| |-BDDexample
|   |-ExampleSystem.py (contains a class called ExampleSystem)
|   |-__init__.py (empty file)
|
|-tests
  |-cucumber
    |-features
      |-steps
        |-EnableSystemStepImpl.py
```

My `setup.py` file is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="BDDexample",
    version="0.2",
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

I then installed this using `pip3 install .`. I also tried `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` followed by `pip3 install dist/BDDexample-0.2-py3-none-any.whl`.

It finds the module BDDexample, and I can test this by typing `pip3 list`, which shows the module.

However, in `EnableSystemStepImpl.py` I have the line:

```
from BDDexample.ExampleSystem import ExampleSystem
```

And I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BDDexample'
```

When I try to run this file.

Why is this happening! It is installed, so why can it not find it. I know there are loads of python import questions but it seems like I am doing everything right.

Comment: I bet u have two different versions of python in your OS.

Comment: @LauReal, nope, I'm using Ubuntu 20 and only have python3.

Comment: `pip3 show BDDExample` or `pip3 list -v` might also be useful to check, could be that your `pip` is installing somewhere outside your `PYTHONPATH` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The file BDDexample.ExampleSystem is not getting extracted from ExampleSystem because it might not be in a direct accessible path for the pc to extract. Please check if it is in your c drive etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it's because I shouldn't have had the `src` folder. I've changed my directory structure to:

```
root
|-setup.py
|-BDDexample
| |-ExampleSystem.py (contains a class called ExampleSystem)
| |-__init__.py (empty file)
|
|-tests
  |-cucumber
    |-features
      |-steps
        |-EnableSystemStepImpl.py
```

And it now works.

I assume `find_packages` couldn't find the `BDDexample` module because it was inside another folder.